# java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500 in android using WCF for android

Tags: java, android, web-services, wcf, ksoap2

I have been trying to get data response from wcf dot net webservices but could not get properly response. From 2 days, gettting this error during connect webservices.

**I also check *SoapEnvelope.VER11* but could not get data.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String METHOD_NAME = "SayHello";

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/IWFPService/";
private static final String URL = "http://*****.svc";

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
    AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
    runner.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String resp;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress("Loading contents..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
        try {
            // SoapEnvelop.VER11 is SOAP Version 1.1 constant
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            //request.addProperty("TestNumber", 12);
            //bodyOut is the body object to be sent out with this envelope
            envelope.bodyOut = request;
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            Log.e(SOAP_ACTION, "-->URL>"+URL);
            Log.e(SOAP_ACTION, "-->METHOD_NAME>"+METHOD_NAME);
            Log.e(SOAP_ACTION, "-->SOAP_ACTION>"+SOAP_ACTION);
            Log.e(SOAP_ACTION, "-->envelope>"+envelope);
             Log.v("", "=========== Request : " + request);
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {
                transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //bodyIn is the body object received with this envelope
            if (envelope.bodyIn != null) {
                //getProperty() Returns a specific property at a certain index.
                SoapPrimitive resultSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn)
                        .getProperty(0);
                resp=resultSOAP.toString();
                Log.e(SOAP_ACTION, "-->>"+resp);
            }
            Log.e(SOAP_ACTION, "<<<-->>"+resp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp = e.getMessage();
        }
        return resp;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        // In this example it is the return value from the web service
        textView.setText(resp);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For
        // example showing ProgessDialog
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress[])
     */
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
        textView.setText(text[0]);
        // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in
        // progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
    }
}
```

}

I have logcat in green color:

```
04-16 12:10:41.363: E/http://tempuri.org/IWFPService/SayHello(22684): -->URL>http://192.168.169.133/WFPeWin2/content/WFPService.svc
04-16 12:10:41.363: E/http://tempuri.org/IWFPService/SayHello(22684): -->METHOD_NAME>SayHello
04-16 12:10:41.363: E/http://tempuri.org/IWFPService/SayHello(22684): -->SOAP_ACTION>http://tempuri.org/IWFPService/SayHello
04-16 12:10:41.363: E/http://tempuri.org/IWFPService/SayHello(22684): -->envelope>org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope@4212da18
04-16 12:10:41.363: V/(22684): =========== Request : SayHello{}
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684): java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at com.example.samplews.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at com.example.samplews.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-16 12:10:41.598: W/System.err(22684):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-16 12:10:41.598: E/http://tempuri.org/IWFPService/SayHello(22684): <<<-->>null
```

What is wrong with my code, any idea??

Comment: Two questions with almost identical titles posted within 2 hours of each other from different users....creepy! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075045/how-to-connect-wcf-with-android-application-and-not-getting-response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well.. HTTP 500 is an internal server error so you should probably check the server is working with SOAPUI or some other tool for starters. Then make sure that you can reach the URL (IP number in this case) from the device and then start debugging the ksaop call.